# sql query only displays rows that have a match in the join

Tags: sql

IN this SQL, it is only returning rows that had data in the col from the join table
(subst_Instructions). But we want it to display the row from main table even if there is not data in the join. Now, its' because of the where SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS is not null presumably.
but without that, it will not show the data from that column. is there a way to say where SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS is not null and null?

```
SELECT * FROM
(
     SELECT ID_KEY, [BATCH] AS column1, [IMPORTDATE], [DATEBILLED], [RX], 
     [DATEDISPENSED], [DAYSUPPLY], [PAYTYPE], [NPI],
     [PHYSICIAN], [COST], [QUANTITY], [MEDICATION], A.[NDC], [PATIENTNAME],   
     [ROUTEOFADMIN], [INVOICECAT], [COPAY], [BRAND], [TIER], [SKILLLEVEL], 
     [STAT] STATUS, [LASTTASKDATE],SEQNO,B.[SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS], 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID_KEY ORDER BY ID_KEY) rn 
   FROM [PBM].[T_CHARGES] A 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN [OGEN].[NDC_M_FORMULARY] B 
       ON A.[NDC] = B.[NDC]  
   WHERE [STAT] NOT IN (3, 4) 
     AND [TIER] <> 'T1'  
 ) a 
 WHERE SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS IS NOT NULL -- rn = 1
```

Comment: What is the outer select for? Results should be the same when you apply WHERE SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS IS NOT NULL directly. (BTW: SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS is a field of table PBM, right? It would have been helpful to have a qualifier A or B on every field.)

Comment: Hi Adams, somehow you are confusing things. In any way you dont't need WHERE SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS IS NOT NULL. Either you want to show all records of PBM and show with them the BST_INSTRUCTIONS if any, then use an outer join. Or you want to show only records of PBM that have a BST_INSTRUCTIONS, then use an inner join. The clause WHERE SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS IS NOT NULL only turns your outer join an inner join effectively.

Comment: i see, but this is the only way it works somewhat. If I remove that last part, then we just get dupes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure not to have any fields of the outer joined table in the WHERE clause. Do [STAT] and [TIER] both belong to the main table? If they belong to the outer joined table, then put the criteria in the ON clause, not in the WHERE clause.

Comment: they are from main. only thing we want from the join table is that substitute_instructions.

Comment: But when there is no matching record in B,  then SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS is null, and then you dismiss the outer joined records with your outer WHERE clause!

Comment: which I dont want to do. We want every row from main table that passes criteria. we just also want to add that little col from the join if there is something there or not.

Comment: Okay. Then remove WHERE SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS IS NOT NULL. That's it.

Comment: yes but then it makes dupes. this is a black hole. I think i should try making an sp. This will be more simple, just go and fetch that little column.

Comment: although why this happening is something i would like to know

Comment: What do you call duplicates? You join PBM with OGEN. When there is more than one matching row in OGEN for one record, then you get more than one record as a result of course. You restrict this in your ON clause. Maybe your ON clause is not complete?

Answer (score 0):

I would use full outer join instead of left outer join.

Comment: Outer join i tried but it returns the exact same rows. I removed the 'where SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS is not null' with the full outer join but then it makes duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You are right - applying the `WHERE SUBSR_INSTRUCTIONS IS NOT NULL` to the outer query means it will only return rows where there is a row in the right side of the join, as it is a column from the right side of the join.

Its easy enough to solve this though by moving this condition into the join criteria instead.

However if your database engine doesnt support multiple join conditions you should join onto a subquery instead as shown below

We also have no need of an outer query. Here is the altered query:

```
SELECT ID_KEY, [BATCH] AS column1, [IMPORTDATE], [DATEBILLED], [RX], 
     [DATEDISPENSED], [DAYSUPPLY], [PAYTYPE], [NPI],
     [PHYSICIAN], [COST], [QUANTITY], [MEDICATION], A.[NDC], [PATIENTNAME],   
     [ROUTEOFADMIN], [INVOICECAT], [COPAY], [BRAND], [TIER], [SKILLLEVEL], 
     [STAT] STATUS, [LASTTASKDATE],SEQNO,B.[SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS], 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID_KEY ORDER BY ID_KEY) rn 
   FROM [PBM].[T_CHARGES] A 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
     ( 
       SELECT * FROM [OGEN].[NDC_M_FORMULARY]
       WHERE [SUBST_INSRUCTIONS] IS NOT NULL  --  <--- Note now only applies to 
                                                --       right hand side.  
     ) B
     ON A.[NDC] = B.[NDC]
   WHERE [STAT] NOT IN (3, 4) 
     AND [TIER] <> 'T1'
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't like the SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS there but anyway, the thing is, i don't want to restrict the data. I want all rows of the main that pass criteria, AND i want the join data but i still want all rows even if they don't have data in the join.

Comment: you WILL get all rows from the left side of the join when the WHERE for the right side is specified in the join condition regardless of whether or not that condition is met for the right hand side of the join. If this query gives you an error then please post the error

Comment: NB I realise you've not actually specified what database engine you are using. Maybe your database engine doesn't like multiple join conditions?

Comment: sql server is used on aZURE